# can i use itemdata(microdata) in my web pages built with html 4

Tags: html

will it be useful or possible to use microdata (itemdata) in my web pages built with HTML 4 code like this

```
<div itemscope>
  <h1>Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: James Cameron (born August 16, 1954) </span>
  <span>Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement schema.org to a non html5 page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651749/implement-schema-org-to-a-non-html5-page)

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on whether the Microdata consumer wanted to check for HTML5-ness via the doctype or otherwise, and then disallow the microdata if the page wasn't HTML5. But it's hard to think of a reason why such a consumer would wish to go to such trouble. How would it benefit from doing so?

Having said that, using `itemscope` without any `itemprop`s probably isn't going to achieve very much.