# Alternative method for using Microdata datetime in HTML5 for HTML4

Tags: microdata, schema.org, html4

This code is for HTML5:

```
<time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2012-01-07T07:07:21+00:00">January 7, 2012</time>
```

Can I use this code for HTML4?

```
<div itemprop="datePublished">
    <span dateCreated="2012-01-07T07:07:21+00:00">January 7, 2012</span>
</div>
```

Or something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Microdata is specified for HTML5, not for HTML 4.01 ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13651749/1591669)). If you don’t care about that:

HTML 4.01 doesn’t define a `dateCreated` attribute for the `span` element. There is also no `time` or `data` element defined. Some would misuse the `abbr` element, but I wouldn’t recommend that. So you’d probably have to use a `span` element, and, ugly, hide the machine-readable date for your visitors.

```html
<span><span itemprop="datePublished" class="hidden">2012-01-07T07:07:21+00:00</span> January 7, 2012</span>
```

But better don’t use Microdata in HTML 4.01 documents in the first place. You could [use RDFa instead](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53140/17633) (you can also [use the Schema.org vocabulary in RDFa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17589792/1591669)).

Comment: I changed The webpage to HTML5 but I think I can use a meta instead <time> tag...right? for example:<meta itemprop="dateCreated" content="2012/3/2 5:30" />

Comment: @user3307827: Yes, when using HTML5, you can use [`meta` and `links` elements with Microdata in the `body`](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633). If not used with Microdata/RDFa, they are only allowed in the `head`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the top line is correct, you can just swap time for span, leaving the rest alone.

Where are you using HTML that the parser breaks on additional attributes/elements?